# Execute shell giving error in Jenkins Freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Whenever I am trying to do execute shell command in freestyle job in Jenkins, however when I try to do same thing while from pipeline, it is running successful.

Following is the error which I am getting in freestyle job:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the drive is full and there is no space left to execute this shell command. See this log:

[image: Log Jenkins]

So what you should do is to make sure that there is enough space on the drive where you run the script/command is available. Maybe you could switch to another partition or delete temporary or unused files.

Comment: Space is available, I checked. My pipeline jobs are running fine on same location but all freestyle jobs are failing and giving me this error

Comment: When you are really sure that enough space is available, maybe then you are missing permissions to write the temp file to JENKINS/workspace/test?

Comment: Can you guide me how to do this ?

Comment: You should find out, who has access (write permissions) to the folder JENKINS/workspace/test. Then you need to know which user is running the Jenkins Freestyle Job. Then you should grant this user write access to the folder JENKINS/workspace/test.

Comment: User which is running the job has the permissions JENKINS/workspace/test. Is it necessary to have 'tmp' folder under JENKINS_HOME?

Comment: like @Kaustubh said , it is actually a permission problem. also tmp folder is created during runtime of your job. His suggestion should fix your issue